# Display Table Cell inconsistency.

Tags: html, css

Hey I was wondering why this happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/dSVGF/

The buttons do not fill the container yet the
anchors do. What is fundamentally different
between the two tags stylistically?

```
<div class="table">
    <a href="#">A</a>
    <a href="#">B</a>
    <a href="#">C</a>
</div>

<div class="table">
    <button href="#">A</button>
    <button href="#">B</button>
    <button href="#">C</button>
</div>


.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.table > * {
    display: table-cell;
    outline: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure it out either :) I'm curious too!

Comment: More interestingly: http://jsfiddle.net/dSVGF/2/ :)

Comment: @Passerby, the rule ".table > *" applies only to immediate children, so theoretically, the div (but not its nested button, A), the button B and the span (again, not its nested button) should apply for this rule. Because the button tag doesn't allow "display: table-cell" on some browsers, button "B" is left out of the loop here.

Comment: @BDawg I know what `>` means. What I want to highlight is that even though `<button>` doesn't accept `display:table-cell`, the next "cell" does seem to know its way to the next position, not directly following the button.

Comment: @BDawg Further more: http://jsfiddle.net/dSVGF/8/ even though Chrome and Firefox doesn't accept `<button>` as `display:table-cell`, they still seem to somehow recognize it as a "cell": it occupies the correct space, and aligned to the corret place.

Comment: @Passerby I see what you're saying now, but I don't think it's recognizing it as a cell in any way. Rather, I think that's the default behavior when a non-table-cell is injected where a table-cell should be. I've modified both of your fiddles to avoid styling the button at all...
http://jsfiddle.net/3LdCV/
http://jsfiddle.net/b3urc/
...yet it still acts the same

Comment: @BDawg That's not true for real tables: http://jsfiddle.net/3LdCV/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/b3urc/1/

Comment: @Passerby, in the case of the real table, it's HTML parser that prevents creation of the illegal DOM structure. In this example, the button becomes not a descendant of the table, but it's previous sibling: http://jsfiddle.net/3LdCV/2/ (also try to explore the DOM with "Inspect element" tool).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that the fundamental difference between these elements is that `<button>` is treated as replaced element (at least by some browsers), and is rendered with the help of non-CSS browser built-in mechanisms. There are several issues in Bugzilla about the rendering limitations of buttons caused by this (e.g. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733914).

IE9+ and Opera seem not to treat `<button>` as a replaced element, which seems more correct according to the latest [HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements), but is still rather unclear in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a button tag actually accepts "display: table-cell" is dependent on the browser, apparently. I ran a quick check in Chrome developer tools: In the calculated styles, the display on the buttons was set to inline-block. When I tried the same in IE10, it accepted the change and the buttons actually sized as table cells.

Answer (score -2):

A button is a clickable element which allows you put anything within such as text, image etc.

An anchor tag is specific for Hyperlinks.

Source: w3schools.com

Comment: I think this is a css question more than an html question. Possibly in the browser stylesheet yet no properties in the inspector seem to have any impact on this.