# Aligning components in forms

Tags: html, css

This is probably something I rather simple I am missing but in my form, I have an `input` of `type = "password"` and a `button` of `type = button` next to each other. After I managed to initially line everything up I decided to set the height to the same height for both components

I expected the outcome to look like this.

[image]

When I used the code below. However when you run the code below you will see the heights are different.

```css
input[type="password"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2vw;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-ckbx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" class="form-inp" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type = "button" class = "form-ckbx" id = "check" title="Show Password">Some Text</button>
</form>
```

How am I able to fix this problem?

*Note*
I am aware of similar question such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726135/css-exact-same-height-and-alignment-of-button-and-input-text-box) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203472/making-a-button-and-textbox-the-same-height-next-to-each-other) but the solutions seem to be ineffective in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS property `box-sizing: border-box`  and will work as you expected.

```css
#password {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2vw;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

.form-ckbx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form>



  <input type="password" class="form-inp" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type = "button" class = "form-ckbx" id = "check" title="Show Password">Some Text</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type="password"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2vw;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
 outline: none;
}

.form-ckbx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" class="form-inp" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type = "button" class = "form-ckbx" id = "check" title="Show Password">Some Text</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The border answer was correct. Whereas when you changed it to padding the answer is no longer correct

Comment: Do you know why the border affects it so much?

Comment: It affects it because it makes the height biger by 1px on top and below

Comment: A simpler solution is to just reduce the heigh by 2 pixels as in 48px. Its how the box model works

Answer (score 2):

Input fields has by default a 1px padding as well as a 1 pixel border hence causing an additional 4px height. So try reset the input padding and adjust the button height in order to accommodate for the difference.

```css
input[type="password"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2vw;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-ckbx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" class="form-inp" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type = "button" class = "form-ckbx" id = "check" title="Show Password">Some Text</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when i copied your code to my computer to test it out it worked... Try change the input[type="password"] to .form-inp

Answer (score -1):

This is due to some paddings, border and outline in the inputbox, try increasing height to something like 60px;

```css
input[type="password"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2vw;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-ckbx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" class="form-inp" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type = "button" class = "form-ckbx" id = "check" title="Show Password">Some Text</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but as this is just guess work I downvoted it

Comment: `something like 60px` is guess work and when you test your answer it is clear it does not work. Whilst you seem to be on the right path your answer is just guess work with the heights

Comment: try running this fiddle and see it for yourself that it works,,  https://jsfiddle.net/xc59u9rp/